# How to save alphanumeric sequence in mongodb and start generating from the last saved sequence in MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb-java, alphanumeric

I have a method that generates an alphanumeric sequence based on a particular pattern. I want to save the generated sequence and when next I want to generate a new one, it should start from the last saved one. I am having an issue with this happening because it is alphanumeric. Also, I want to put the generated IDs in an excel file.

These two methods below check if it already exists and also try to fetch the last item saved.

```
 public Optional<Terminal> findByGeneratedTerminalIDs(String id){
        return Optional.ofNullable(this.collection.findOne(Filters.eq("generatedTerminalID", id)));
    }

    public Optional<FindIterable<Terminal>> findLastGeneratedTerminalID(String generatedTerminalID) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(this.collection.find(Filters.eq("generatedTerminalID", generatedTerminalID)).
                sort(Sorts.descending("generatedTerminalID")).limit(1));

    }
```

Here is the updated repository

```
private JacksonMongoCollection<Sequence> collection;

    public SequenceRepository(JacksonMongoCollection<Sequence> collection) {
        this.collection = collection;
    }


public Sequence save(Sequence sequence) {
    collection.save(sequence);
    return sequence;
}

public Sequence findAllSequences(Sequence sequence) {
    return collection.find(Filters.eq("generatedTerminalID", sequence.getGeneratedTerminalID())).first();
}
```

public BaseResponse generateTerminalIDs(TerminalIDDTO terminalDto) {

```
Sequence sequence = new Sequence();
sequence.setNext(0);
sequenceRepository.save(sequence);

int totalLength = 8;
int numberOfIds = terminalDto.getNumberOfTerminals();
int countRemainingSymbols = totalLength - START.length();
//there should be only 1 row at all times
sequence = this.sequenceRepository.findAllSequences(sequence);
int start = sequence.getNext();//start generation of sequences from the value of next
int next = start + numberOfIds;//this will be next value of sequence.next
for (int i = start; i < next; i++) {
    StringBuilder end = new StringBuilder();
    int current = i;
    int remainder = current % ALPHANUMERIC.length();//the index of next character
    do {
        end.append(ALPHANUMERIC.charAt(remainder));
        current /= ALPHANUMERIC.length();//update to check if we need to add more characters
        remainder = current % ALPHANUMERIC.length();//update index, only used if more chars are needed
    } while (current > 0);
    int padCount = countRemainingSymbols - end.length();
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(START).append("-");//- is for easier debugging, remove it for your case
    for (int j = 0; j < padCount; j++) {
        result.append("0");
    }
    result.append(end.reverse());
    log.info("These are the values {}", result);
}
//update next value and save in db
sequence.setNext(next);
sequenceRepository.save(sequence);

return BaseResponse.builder().status(true).message("TerminalIDs have been generated").build();
```

}

I want the saving and checking if it exists to be done in this method I posted above. What is the best way to go about it?

Comment: @chaosfire here is a follow up to the question I asked earlier.

Comment: Should id be unique in the entire database? Or is it unique only in a concrete set of terminals, for example set1(ids - `0000`, `0001`, `0002`, and so on), set2(ids - `0000`, `0001`, and so on)?

Comment: It should be unique in the entire database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it adding a new table to db. Since it has to be unique for entire db, this table will hold a single row, which keeps track of next integer to use for id generation.

I'll assume you use spring data, then your entity could be something like this:

```
public class Sequence {

  private String id;
  private int next;

  //getters and setters
}
```

The repository:

```
@Repository
public interface SequenceRepository extends MongoRepository<Sequence, String> {
}
```

Assuming you are using mongo from question tag.

Initial value for next should be zero.

```
Sequence sequence = new Sequence();
sequence.setNext(0);
this.repository.saveAndFlush(sequence);
```

Initialise and save in db at appropriate time, maybe app startup. Just do this initialization only once.

Then generation method might be like this:

```
@Autowired
private SequenceRepository repository;

public BaseResponse generateTerminalIDs(TerminalIDDTO terminalDto) {
  Terminal terminal = new Terminal();
  int totalLength = 8;
  int numberOfIds = terminalDto.getNumberOfTerminals();
  int countRemainingSymbols = totalLength - START.length();
  //there should be only 1 row at all times
  Sequence sequence = this.repository.findAll().get(0);
  int start = sequence.getNext();//start generation of sequences from the value of next
  int next = start + numberOfIds;//this will be next value of sequence.next
  for (int i = start; i < next; i++) {
    StringBuilder end = new StringBuilder();
    int current = i;
    int remainder = current % ALPHANUMERIC.length();//the index of next character
    do {
      end.append(ALPHANUMERIC.charAt(remainder));
      current /= ALPHANUMERIC.length();//update to check if we need to add more characters
      remainder = current % ALPHANUMERIC.length();//update index, only used if more chars are needed
    } while (current > 0);
    int padCount = countRemainingSymbols - end.length();
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(START).append("-");//- is for easier debugging, remove it for your case
    for (int j = 0; j < padCount; j++) {
      result.append("0");
    }
    //this should be outside pad loop
    result.append(end.reverse());
  }
  //update next value and save in db
  sequence.setNext(next);
  this.repository.saveAndFlush(sequence);
  return BaseResponse.builder().status(true).message("TerminalIDs have been generated").build();
}
```

There are some assumptions here, but this is the overall algorithm you should follow.

**Important:** This solution does not take into account possible simultaneous access to the table, which may lead to duplicating ids. If you have such use cases, you might want to consider:

1. Locking the table during `generateTerminalIDs` execution, thus forcing other threads who want access for next to wait until all ids are generated.
2. Get next, and update it right after, before id generation. Locking the table during get and update may still be a good idea, but other threads that want access will wait less.

**Edit:** SaveAndFlush is equivalent for create or update. In spring it's implemented in this way - if entity has id property(`sequence.id != null` in this case), do an update, otherwise do create(insert). For your case, create the row when initializing new table, update it when ids are created.

About `findAll()` - it returns a list with all rows/entites from a table. Here `repository.findAll()` will return `List<Sequence>`. `repository.findAll().get(0)` will return `Sequence`, the **first and only** row in the table.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Having some issues. I am not using Springboot. Thus, I do not have access to saveAndFlush(). Also, there is no findAll.get(0). What will findAll.get(0) return so I can better understand how to implement here. Currently, thinking of using find.first() in MongoJackson

Comment: @Curious Check edit.

Comment: Currently only 0 and the inputed number is saving in the db . I will update the question with save and findAll equivalent I created. Also, which part of the code should I place this Sequence sequence = new Sequence();
sequence.setNext(0);
this.repository.saveAndFlush(sequence); inside the function where it is being generated or outside

Comment: @Curious I don't really understand first question. What is inputted number? About second question, where to put - `... sequence.setNext(0); ...`, definitely outside, this is initialization of your sequence. Let me citate myself - `Initialise and save in db at appropriate time, maybe app startup. Just do this initialization only once.`

Comment: The first question I meant terminalDto. The issue is that the sequence (that is the terminal ID) is not being saved and if I delete what I have in the DB it will throw error that sequence is null

Comment: @Curious I'm not expert on mongo, but as far as i am aware `collection.save()` should do insert or update, depending on if there is id. I am afraid there is not enough data to fix this issue, at least for me. My only idea is, if the problem is only when updating sequence, you could use some of `collection.update...()` methods, but that's a shot in the dark.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So, I have found a way around saving, the only difficulty right now is saving a list (of the sequence). That's all that's left

Comment: Made some modifications and got the desired results. thanks!